# Remove closed post from flag queue when voting to close on an already-closed question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

Because the moderator queue is asynchronous, it often happens that two moderators are looking at the same question in the queue at the same time.

It also often happens that two moderators will vote to close a question.  However, only *one* moderator can do this.

In this case, the moderator who tries to close the question after it's been closed gets notified with the following dialog:

[image: Question is now closed dialog]

It's obvious from the behavior that there's a hook on the close button that checks the status of the question before the close dialog is presented to the moderator.

The question is, *why do I have to refresh the page*?

Why can't the dialog look like this:

[image: Proposed change to dialog behavior.]

And have the behavior that the entry is simply removed from the list (it's easy enough to remove the DOM elements, since you've already hooked into the close button on this particular post, no?) once the dialog is dismissed?

There's a case to be made that the moderator still has access to the question once the original dialog is dismissed, but to be honest, 99.999% of the time, if another moderator has handled the flag, we really don't want to see it in the queue.

To handle the 0.001% of the time where you *do* want to see the post anyways, because the dialog isn't modal, the link is still clickable before the dialog is dismissed.

That said, please simply remove the entry from the queue instead of forcing a refresh of the page when this happens.

*Or* at the very least, compress the question to just the title like any other item in the queue where the flag has been handled (just show the title).

Comment: I agree, and the same goes for non-moderator reviewing, as well. Reviewing suggested edits / close votes etc. I often get the same behaviour and have to dismiss the dialog and click "skip", which seems silly.